# ERROR in src/app/auth/auth.module.ts(30,94): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-recaptcha'

Tags: angular

when I run ng serve -o it gives me this error
ERROR in src/app/auth/auth.module.ts(30,94): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-recaptcha'.

I am tryign to build angular project

This is the error I am getting

ERROR in ./src/app/auth/auth.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng-recaptcha' in 'C:\Code Base\DMS Pro\EDMS4.0_DMSPro\src\app\auth'
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

ERROR in src/app/auth/auth.module.ts(30,94): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-recaptcha'.

Comment: That error usually happens when you have forgotten to add the library to your "imports" section of your Angular module.

Comment: it is there but shows error

Comment: import { RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS, RecaptchaFormsModule, RecaptchaModule, RecaptchaSettings } from 'ng-recaptcha';

Comment: Post your package.json, your root module (typically app.module.ts) and your auth.module.ts.  If you're consuming it in auth.module, are you exporting it from your root module?  If you're using a shared module, please post that as well.